# Saying “that” like “It’s nice that...” or “It makes me sad that...”

Tags: grammar

I understand using relative clauses like 私が食べた食べものはおいしかったです but how do you translate “that” for expressing emotions?

Answer (score 5):

While the construction that corresponds to this kind of phrase exists in Japanese, the word "that" is not directly translatable, I'm afraid. Translating between Japanese and English is not compatible with "word-for-word" translations a good amount of the time.

This being said, this is a grammar point that might be expressed in this fashion:

> X {のは/ことは} Y-adjective です。

...where X is an event, an action, or a thing, and Y is an adjective that expresses how you feel about it.

Expressing a sense of happiness over an occurred event can be expressed in this way as well:

> X が　{Y-verb in て form} よかったです。

Expanding on your example phrases:

> 学校で友達ができてよかったですね。
> It's nice that you have made friends at school.
>
> もう会えないことは悲しいです。
> It makes me sad that we won't meet again.

Here, I used いい (good, nice) to describe the event that is 学校で友達ができる(having made friends at school).　いい conjugates to よかった in the past tense.

Similarly, I used 悲しい (sad) to describe the event that is もう会えない (never meeting again).

EDIT: Thanks to Chocolate for pointing out that my previous いい example sounded like you could be jealous instead. It has been replaced with the construction -てよかった, which can translate to being glad for something.

Comment: なるほど、どうも！！！you’re right, these kinds of things can’t easily be translated!!!

Comment: `学校で友達を作ったのはいいです。` doesn't sound natural, I'm afraid... 「学校で友達ができてよかったですね。」って感じのほうが・・・（ちなみに、「学校で友達ができて、 **いい**ですね。」って言うと、なんか羨ましがってるみたいに聞こえるような・・・）

Comment: @Chocolate それは本当ですね。では、答えを直します。確かに羨ましい感じがしますね。いつもどおりありがとう。